# What type of paper is commonly used to print flyers

Tags: print-design, print-production, paper

for example: I'm printing my design out onto paper but which type of paper is most environmentally friendly and has a slight shinny finish:

- glossy card
- cover
- matt

this is for my graphics GCSE coursework and so I have to make a final piece at the end

Comment: What's the purpose of the flyers? Do you have a budget?

Comment: the reason I'm doing a flyer is because its part of the design task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my... Homework... Here I go.

> which type of paper is most environmentally friendly

There are two main types of "environmentally friendly".

**1)** The one made with already recycled paper.

**2)** One that is certified as environmentally friendly. The main seal I know is http://fsc.org which verifies that all the process is environmental friendly, including reforestation.

> What type of paper is commonly used to print flyers

The three main categories are

**a)** Not coated. It is cheap but the collors are dull. For one ink flyer is fine.

**b)** Coated. For a full color flyer. Like the ones on a color magazine.

**c)** Special papers. Texturized for example.

> a slight shinny finish

A glossy paper has glossy finish.

A matt has matt finish.

A satin has a slight shinny finish.

But this can be modified using a varnish.

Comment: what materials are used to make satin paper?